# Native heap continues to grow by regular amounts though java heap holds steady, then fatal signal 6 crash

Tags: java, android

My Android app loads a great deal of images using Universal Image Loader in a series of fragments.  I've checked hprofs in Memory Analyzer and after fixing various leaks am not seeing any more.  DDMS java heap size increases a bit to around 16, but meanwhile I'm checking Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize and seeing that inflate by around 90MB with each fragment replace.  Around 600MB native heap the app crashes fatal signal 6 SIGABRT, usually while trying to build the image-heavy UI on a data return.  But there's never an out of memory error.

Is the native heap increase causing the fatal signal 6 crash, or is it stalled UI?  And what's the best way to debug the continued increase in native heap?

Comment: do you use any native library?

Comment: no, no native libraries

Comment: What version of Android and what device is it?

Comment: getting this on both kitkat and lollipop on various devices - it's not device or version specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images were a red herring.  The fatal 6 was indeed related to the ever-growing native heap.

Besides lots of images, the app created a lot of custom TextViews for each screen, and the previous developer had a Typeface.createFromAsset call in the init for these custom TextViews.  So thousands of Typefaces were being added to the native heap.
Lazily creating a static typeface once only fixed this.

To debug, best approach was to remove the suspect.  After hours of fiddling with images and UniversalImageLoader config settings, I took out image loading (should have done this first) and still saw the heap grow out of control - thus had to look elsewhere, and then it was minutes to find.